# InvalidOperationException: The property 'X' is not a declared property on type 'Y'

Tags: .net, entity-framework, orm, entity-framework-6

I have an entity that looks like this:

```
public class SomeType
{
    public char CharacterProperty { get; set; }
}
```

When the `DbContext` is initialised, I get an error:

> The property 'CharacterProperty' is not a declared property on type 'SomeType'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently Entity Framework doesn't support `char` properties. I fixed this by changing it to a `string`.